# How to install FFMpeg in WampServer 2.0 (Windows XP)

Tags: php, windows-xp, ffmpeg

I need to install the ffmpeg PHP extension on my localhost so I can test few of my scripts but I am having troubles figuring out how to do that.

I have WampServer 2.0 with PHP 5.2.9-2, my OS is Windows XP. Please somebody give me step by step instructions.

I have found some Windows builds here: sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-php/files/

What I have done so far:

1. Download ffmpeg_new from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-php/files/
2. Copy php_ffmpeg.dll from the php5 folder to the C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.9-2\ext
3. Copy files from common to the windows/system32 folder
4. Add extension=php_ffmpeg.dll to php.ini file
5. Restarted all services (Apache, PHP...)

But I am getting this error when trying to use ffmpeg (plus ffmpeg is not even listed in phpinfo()):

```
Warning: dl() [function.dl]: Not supported in multithreaded Web servers - use extension=ffmpeg.dll in your php.ini in C:\wamp\www\hunnyhive\application\modules\default\controllers\MyAccountController.php on line 314
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question here as well (since you've posted it on stack overflow as well)...

Doesn't look like the problem is with ffmpeg... the warning is about the use of the dl function. Multi-threaded PHP does not support dynamic loading of any PHP extension, so you'll need to make sure the .dll file for it is placed wherever the rest of your php modules live.

What you really need to figure out is why the extension doesn't load despite the fact you've got the "extension=php_ffmpeg.dll" directive in your php.ini. Usually you can see any startup errors in your apache error log (such as PHP saying it can't load a library). Also, have you taken a look at a phpinfo() and verified ffmpeg isn't present (shouldn't be since the extension_loaded returns false), but perhaps it's there under a different name.

Answer (score 1):

hey use extension_loaded() instead of dl

Answer (score 1):

http://sergey89.ru/files/ffmpeg-php-win32-all.zip

1. unpack ffmpeg-php-win32-all.zip
2. Copying php_ffmpeg.dll to the \wamp\php4\extension\ (for php5 it's
   \wamp\bin\php\ext)
3. Copying  avcodec.dll & avformat.dll and any other in package to the \windows\system32\
4. Editing \wamp\apache\apache2.xx\bin\php.ini - adding line extension=php_ffmpeg.dll
5. Restarting Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://sergey89.ru/files/ffmpeg-php/ffmpeg-php-5.3-win32-all.zip

For PHP 5.3